# New Scipy sparse.csgraph.connected_components error - ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, valueerror, type-mismatch

I have recently been getting an error in my code that has not been changed and have not had any issues with in the past. I am running `sparse.csgraph.connected_components(adj_mat, directed=False, return_labels=True)` with correct data that has worked previously. But now when I go back to re-run the same code with the same data I am getting the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1l5O.png)

Has anyone else encountered this for this function or a similar issue and have any suggestions?

I have made sure that the data types are consistent and make sense and have even checked numpy and python versions that are compatible with this version of scipy to make sure that is not the case.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, please prefer post code as image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Instead%20of%20using%20images%2C%20paste,%2C%20or%20use%20code%20fences.)